# PHP, getting different array value from different foreach

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm quite lost, in the following code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
        $similar_games[$row->game_id]['id'][] = $row->id;
        $similar_games[$row->game_id]['name'][] = $row->name;
        $similar_games[$row->game_id][$type] = 0;
    }
        foreach($similar_games as $originalGameKey => $originalGame){
            //Can be a case where union gets unset, and not populated.  scares ksort();
            $union = array();
            $similar_values = array();

            $union = $similar_concepts; 

            foreach($originalGame['id'] as $similarGameKey => $similarGame){
                if(!isset($union[$similarGame])){
                    $union[] = $similarGame;
                }
            }
            foreach($originalGame['id'] as $similarGameKey => $similarGame){
                if(isset($union[$similarGame])){
                    $similar_values[] = $similarGame;
                }
            }
            $similar_games[$originalGameKey]["union"] = $similar_values;
       }
```

At the line `$similar_values[] = $similarGame;` I'm attempting to get the `$row->name` rather than the `$row->id`

But I don't know how to make the foreach which is based on the ['id'] access the ['name'] values.

If this is too confusing, I can try to clarify, but I'm having trouble here myself.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed:

```
foreach($originalGame['id'] as $similarGameKey => $similarGame){
                if(isset($union[$similarGame])){
                    $similar_values[] = $similarGame;
                }
            }
            $similar_games[$originalGameKey]["union"] = $similar_values;
```

To:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($originalGame['id']);$i++){
                if(isset($union[$originalGame['id'][$i]])){
                    $similar_values[] = $originalGame['name'][$i];
                }
            }
            $similar_games[$originalGameKey]["union"] = $similar_values;
```